Telegram bot - Get poll results
I'm working on developing a Telegram bot that can initiate polls in group chats and gather the votes in those polls.
I've successfully implemented the creation of polls using the sendPoll API endpoint. Once a poll is created, I store both the message ID and the poll ID.
Now, I'm wondering how I can retrieve the votes submitted for the poll. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

You can listen to the Poll (Update.poll) type updates to retrieve poll information.
Here's how:

Telegram sends updates (Update.poll) whenever someone votes or the poll closes.
Listen for these updates to track the poll's progress.
You can close the poll by using the saved chat_id and message_id to call the stopPoll API endpoint.
This triggers a final Update.poll event with all the results you need.
In this update, you'll find details like the total number of voters (Poll.total_voter_count) (see docs) and how many people chose each option (PollOptions.voter_count) (see docs).

This way, you can keep track of your poll and analyze the results once it's finished.
Edit:
To retrieve information about the user who voted on the poll, firstly, the poll must be non-anonymous. Secondly, you need to listen to the poll_answer update type.
Check the PollAnswer documentation for detailed info on properties it has.
If you wish to save (maybe to a database) which user voted for which option, you must save it as the event happens, as there's no way to retrieve it later.
Edit 2:
It seems, you don't have to listen to the Poll update at all. When you stop a poll, Bot returns the completed poll details. So, it's simple as:
chatId = -4194582143
msgId = 0 # set this when you send the poll
pollId = ""


def stop_poll():
    baseurl = f"api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/stopPoll"
    parameters = {
        "chat_id": chatId,
        "message_id" msgId,
    }
    response = requests.get(url=baseurl, data=parameters, timeout=15)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Error while posting to telegram API %s", response.status_code)
    else:
        print(response.json())
        # response will contain the stopped poll details 
        # this includes total_voter_count, `options` with voters_count for each option
        # check more here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#poll

But, once again, if you want to track users who voted which option, you need to recursively call the getUpdates and check poll_answer type of Updates.
Edit 3
import requests
import time

def get_updates(bot_token):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/getUpdates?allowed_updates=[\"poll\", \"poll_answer\"]"
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        updates_json = response.json()
        if updates_json["ok"]:
            updates = updates_json["result"]
            return updates
        else:
            print("Failed to fetch updates. Response not okay.")
            return None
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch updates. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return None

def process_poll(poll):
    # Implement your logic to handle incoming polls here
    print("Received a new poll:", poll)

def process_poll_answer(poll_answer):
    # Implement your logic to handle incoming poll answers here
    print("Received a poll answer:", poll_answer)


def process_updates(updates):
    for update in updates:
        if "poll" in update:
            process_poll(update["poll"])
        elif "poll_answer" in update:
            process_poll_answer(update["poll_answer"])

def fetch_and_process_updates(bot_token):
    while True:
        updates = get_updates(bot_token)
        if updates:
            process_updates(updates)
        # Add a delay between each update request to avoid flooding the API
        time.sleep(1)  # You can adjust the delay as needed


BOT_TOKEN = "your_bot_token_here"
fetch_and_process_updates(BOT_TOKEN)

Hope this helps.

Thank you for your response. If feasible, could you provide an example code snippet for handling the update.poll event? Additionally, I'm curious if it's possible to retrieve details about the users who have voted. Thank you!

Are you using any modules/Bot API wrapper to build your Telegram bot or are you relying on plain http requests from your script? I'm not good with python but if you mention the module used, I'll try to draft one. Meanwhile, here's a detailed example file that I've created in Dart Hope this helps.

Also, I've edited the original answer to add info about how to get information about the user who marked/removed the vote.

i am using "telegram" module. but for creating poll in group chat i am using http request. thank you

Here is the function i use to create poll
def new_telegram_poll():
baseurl = (f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendpoll")
parameters={ "chat_id": -4194582143,
"question": 'Friday Grand Sport 12:30-14:00?',
"options":json.dumps([
'+',
'-'
]),
"is_anonymous":False,
"allows_multiple_answers":False,
"type":"regular",
}
response = requests.get(url=baseurl,data=parameters, timeout=15)
if response.status_code != 200:
print("Error while posting to telegram API %s", response.status_code)
else:
// code to save poll id and message id

hey, thanks for sharing the code snippet. i've edited my original answer once again to show how to get poll info.

Thank you very much for the edits, but unfortunately, stopping the poll is not an option. I am still confused about how I can listen to poll updates. If possible, could you provide an example? Using getUpdates doesn't seem to help; it just returns a 200 OK response without any data.
thank you

Hey, thanks for writing back. I'm not good with python, but from my basic understanding, I've written a code to listen to the "poll" and "poll_answer" updates. Edited the original answer once again to contain the code. Let me know if this works. Regards :)

Thank you very much for the edits. Yes, they worked.
